# Post message creating message in Draft State Microsoft Graph API Java

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

When I try to send a message using Microsoft Graph Java API, It's state is Draft.

```
Authentication.initialize(appId);
    final String accessToken = Authentication.getUserAccessToken(appScopes);

    authProvider = new SimpleAuthProvider(accessToken);

    // Create default logger to only log errors
    DefaultLogger logger = new DefaultLogger();
    logger.setLoggingLevel(LoggerLevel.DEBUG);

    // Build a Graph client
    graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder()
        .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
        .logger(logger)
        .buildClient();

    IMailFolderDeltaCollectionPage mailFolderCollectionPage = graphClient.me().mailFolders().delta()
        .buildRequest().get();
    AtomicReference<String> inBoxFolderId = new AtomicReference<>("");
    while (mailFolderCollectionPage.getNextPage() != null) {
      List<MailFolder> mailFolders = mailFolderCollectionPage.getCurrentPage();
      mailFolders.forEach(m -> {
        if (m.displayName.equals("Inbox")) {
          inBoxFolderId.set(m.id);
        }
          });

      mailFolderCollectionPage = mailFolderCollectionPage.getNextPage().buildRequest().get();
    }

    IMessageDeltaCollectionPage messageCollectionPage = graphClient.me().mailFolders("Inbox")
        .messages().delta().buildRequest().get();

    Message backedMessaged = null;

    while (messageCollectionPage.getNextPage() != null) {
      System.out.println("messageCollectionPage = " + messageCollectionPage);
      List<Message> messageList = messageCollectionPage.getCurrentPage();
      backedMessaged = messageList.get(0);
      break;
    }

   graphClient.me().mailFolders("Inbox").messages().buildRequest().post(backedMessaged);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create an Outlook message, its state will remain as draft until you send it. You should use the `send` request to send your message. It will then not be marked as draft anymore.

Look here for more informations : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/graph/api/message-send?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http